# Image not being read, 'NoneType has no attribute read'

Tags: python

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 17:39:07] "GET /hello?url=http://i.imgur.com/HYMQOl7.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 781
https://lh4.ggpht.com/mJDgTDUOtIyHcrb69WM0cpaxFwCNW6f0VQ2ExA7dMKpMDrZ0A6ta64OCX3H-NMdRd20=w300
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/SR/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/Users/SR/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "helloworld.py", line 29, in expandit
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string('temp.png')
  File "/Users/SR/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 117, in image_to_string
    image.save(input_file_name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I really don't know what the problem is. The function of imread() is supposed to be as I used it, at least that's what I think.

Here's my Python code:

```
import urllib2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import data
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
from bottle import route, run, request, get



@get('/hello')
def expandit():
    url = request.get('url')
    if url == '':
        return {"success": "false"}
    else:
        image_original = io.imread(url) #creates a temp file
        image = rgb2gray(image_original)

        io.imsave(temp.png, image)

        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(temp.png)

        return {"text": txt, "success": "true"}

run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```

It would be awesome if I could be pushed in the right direction. 
Thanks a ton.

Comment: `if url == '':` does nothing to catch `None`. One way would be to change this to `if not url:` which should stop your error. `url = request.get('url')` returns `url = None` not `''` if it fails to find the key.

Comment: @roganjosh - Thanks for the reply. I just tried doing that, but same error

Comment: So immediately before `image_original = io.imread(url)`, what do you get from `print(url)`?

Comment: @SR1 override url before if condition and check if that works. I have shared a url that's working for me.

Comment: @VikashSingh This time I get `https://lh4.ggpht.com/mJDgTDUOtIyHcrb69WM0cpaxFwCNW6 (your url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/SR/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/Users/SR/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "helloworld.py", line 27, in expandit
    io.imsave(temp.png, image)
NameError: global name 'temp' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 17:28:28] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 500 746`

Comment: `temp.png` should be `'temp.png'` in your code

Comment: When I make that change, it says 'str' object has no attribute 'save': `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: Share Line number also along with new code. Basically update your question.

Comment: @VikashSingh done

Comment: updated code. check now. make sure you have installed `tesseract-ocr` other wise you will get this error `No such file or directory: 'tesseract'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `url` is `None`

Try this code:

```
image_original = io.imread(None)
```

Will give the same error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Change your code if condition :

```
# to test override url
url = 'https://lh4.ggpht.com/mJDgTDUOtIyHcrb69WM0cpaxFwCNW6f0VQ2ExA7dMKpMDrZ0A6ta64OCX3H-NMdRd20=w300'
if url:
    image_original = io.imread(url)

    # read image and convert it.
    image = rgb2gray(image_original)
    io.imsave('temp.png', image)
    im = Image.open('temp.png')
    bg = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (255,255,255))
    bg.paste(im)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bg)

    return {"text": txt, "success": "true"}

else:
    return {"success": "false"}
```

Make sure you have tesseract-ocr installed

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Comment: Although this is almost certainly the answer, OP is claiming in comments that this doesn't fix their issue.

Comment: @roganjosh just read in the comment: updating suggestion. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is working as a standalone solution - but the BottlePy code continues to remain unresponsive.

Comment: I keep getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @SR1 you tried overriding the `url` value in the `BottlePy` python code. it still didn't work??

Comment: @VikashSingh I mean it worked as in I could see the result of the print statement in the console, it registered the URL. But the server error persists in Bottle.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, if you override the `url` value in BottlePy code (As I have shown). and it works then your url param is getting passed incorrectly. If the override also doesn't work, then we have a different problem.

Comment: Could it be because of the lack of single quotes?

Comment: yes. That is the reason. correct it and we will see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152171/discussion-between-vikash-singh-and-sr1).